# How to make ReSharper put "if" from "else if" on a new line?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, jetbrains-ide

I want to format the "else if" block like this:

```
if (something) {

} else
if (somethingElse) {

}
```

ReSharper is currently set to do this instead:

```
if (something) {

} else if (somethingElse) {

}
```

How can I change this?

Comment: It may be possible, but its not very readable, just my two cents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can activate it in ReSharper's options:

[image]